# app service and vm in azure with same virtual network

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have a small site which build on .net framework and I want to host the site in azure app service with basic pricing tier.

I want to avoid using sql databases service azure because of pricing.

So that I want to host my database in VM, because I already have the sql server licence.

Is it possible to map the database in VM with the app service?

Please suggest the better ways of doing it.

Comment: i think they allow to host mysql in webapps. not mssql

Comment: oh, if you are asking to host mssql in a vm and reach that vm from webapp - its possible. its called vnet integration

Answer (score 2):

From your description, you want to host SQL Server on Azure VM. It's possible to access the DB on Azure VM from App service.

Here are two options for you:

- [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). If so, you need to upgrade to a **Standard or Premium Plan** to configure a VNet.
  [image]
- [App Service integration with hybrid connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections). It enables your app to access a single TCP endpoint per hybrid connection.
  [image]

In my opinion, VNet integration is better to use need TCP and UDP connections and it also works with function apps. The Hybrid connection is better to use that you want to provide access from multiple networks. For example, you can access the DB from the on-premise network.

For more references, you could read [this blog](https://www.petri.com/connect-azure-web-apps-premises).